# SQL Server db_datareader cannot Script Table as, what permission is missing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a user with db_datareader permissions on a SQL Server 2012 DB who cannot "Script Table as..." in SSMS without a long delay and error that they do not have Create table permissions.

It appears that there are specific permissions that are needed when doing "Script as...", anyone know what they are?

Specifically they are trying to "Script Table as > SELECT To > New Query Window"

Comment: Are you sure the error is that they need "create" permission? Try `grant view definition to TheUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grant view definition to the user solve the issue